# How can I override the location.assign or location.replace functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to override the `location.assign` function, so that I can ensure that the URLs set by it will always be absolute. But I can't seem to get it to work: when I use `Xmlhttprequest.open` as follows, it works fine:

```
var oldOpen;
oldOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

// override the native open()
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(){

    //Prepend our proxyURL
    arguments[1] = prependURL+arguments[1];

    // call the native open()
    oldOpen.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

But for `location.assign` this technique does not work. This is what I'm trying:

```
var old;
old = window.location.assign.prototype.constructor;

window.location.assign.prototype.constructor = function(){
    console.log('dd');
    console.log(arguments);
            alert('ff');
}

old.apply(this,arguments);
```

When I run this (I'm doing my testing in Chrome), the result is `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`. How can I override `location.assign` to get my desired behavior?

Answer (score 9):

The `assign` method can't be modified per spec. See [The `Location` Interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#the-location-interface) in the WHATWG HTML Living Standard.

You'll notice an `[Unforgeable]` extended attribute defined for the `Location` interface. That's defined in WebIDL: "it indicates that the attribute or operation will be reflected as an ECMAScript property in a way that means **its behavior cannot be modified**". See [`[Unforgeable]`](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/WebIDL/#Unforgeable) in the W3C WebIDL editor's draft.

I found this thread after trying to modify the `replace` method, which is defined on the same `[Unforgeable]` interface, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `XMLHttpRequest` is a *constructor* function, but `location` is already constructed.

You may be able to just override it directly:

```
var old_location_replace = location.replace;
location.replace = function(url) {
    // ....
};
```

I think I'd try to find a different way to solve the problem, though, rather than mucking about with the basic operations of the built-in objects of the environment. I wouldn't guarantee at all, for instance, that the above would work well cross-browser (IE, in particular, generally doesn't make "host" functions and objects real JavaScript functions and objects, which would be necessary for this to work).

A better approach would be to have a function that all of your code calls, which in turn calls `location.replace` and `location.assign`. If you're trying to intercept calls from code you don't control, that's obviously not going to work, but you have to consider very carefully whether doing that is really appropriate.

Comment: What im trying is building a kind of proxy where i enclose any given page in my own kind of browser to be able to modify the page. So i dont have full control of all location.href calls in the page.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.assign` is a function - the prototype that you're attempting to access is the `function` prototype. Try the following:

```
var old;
old = window.location.assign;

window.location.assign = function(){
  console.log('dd');
  console.log(arguments);
  alert('ff');
  old.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: This work without errors, but when i call location.href="test.html", i dont get the alert, the page just redirects as normal. What i wanted to do is to be able to change the called url, in this case test.html, to e.g. http://mydomain.com/test.html

Comment: Although some browsers will allow you to modify native DOM objects like window.location, chrome and possibly others will not allow you to replace these.