# URL Query parameter value change event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, query-string

I need to call a function on each URL Query parameter value change.

Initially when page loads, the URL will be

```
https://example.com/?some_key=some_value
```

whenever some value changes to another value

```
https://example.com/?some_key=some_other_value
```

I need to call a function.

How can I set a listener for this url query param value change in my page?

Comment: you should show us your page code, in order to view how your code change parameters value. You also should explain how you try to change value and what goes wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I override the location.assign or location.replace functions in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258866/how-can-i-override-the-location-assign-or-location-replace-functions-in-javascri)